# Show that $x_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}$ for every $ n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Show that $x_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $ where $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}$.

- Clearly $\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound
- Let $M>0$ is any upper bound
- Suppose to contrary that $M<\frac{1}{2}$
- Since  M is upper bound  we have $ \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \leq M $ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
- In  particular for $n=2$, $1/2 \leq M$

therefore $\frac{1}{2} \leq M <\frac{1}{2}$ contradiction thus $\frac{1}{2}\leq M$ so supremum is $\frac{1}{2}$

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: After you say "clearly $\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound" you are done, no? At least that is what your title and question are asking about. Forget the supremum, that's what you need to prove: the "clearly" part of your statement

Comment: @QC_QAOA Is my supremum part correct?

Comment: @QC_QAOA I have a doubt since I use $n=2$ is it ok?

Comment: The proof by contradiction is unnecessary. You can exhibit 1/2 as being in the set, and once an upper bound is in the set, it's the supremum.

Comment: If you really want the supremum part, it's enough that your upper bound is in the sequence. So not only is it the supremum it's also the maximum of the sequence

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is exactly $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working shows that you are actually solving a separate problem, show that the supremum of the sequence is $\frac12$.

For odd $n=2m+1$, $x_{n}=x_{2m+1} = -\frac1{2m+1}<0$.

For even $n=2m$, $x_n=x_{2m}=\frac1{2m}$ is decreasing. Hence the maximum of the sequence is attained when $n=2$.

Comment: To show that the supremum of the sequence can we use my method? I have a doubt that put $n=2$ in my contrary

Comment: If someone substitue $n=4$ inside, he can conclude that an upperbound is at least $\frac14$, but he can't claim that it is the supremum.  Hence more reasoning is required.